# Cleaning ubuntu from residual files left after removed packages

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, uninstall, purge

I removed lot of packages over the time from system using apt remove instead of apt purge. Once I removed a package using apt remove and cleaned my system using bleachbit. After somedays I ran the apt purge command to remove files that were left by old package which was removed week ago. So, my question is that, how can I use apt purge to get rid of all the files of packages that I ever removed using apt remove?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of 12.04 you can just do

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge {packagename}
```

for packages that already have been removed.

This will do them all in 1 nifty command ...

```
dpkg --purge `dpkg --get-selections | grep deinstall | cut -f1`
```

---

Old skool:

If you want to do this visually: install [Synaptic](http://packages.ubuntu.com/synaptic) [image: Install Synaptic] from the Software Center and run `synaptic`. You ca find what you want to remove in the "Not Installed (residual config)" section.

Comment: That nifty command works perfectly :)